# Передача больших файлов TCP От сервера C++ на клиент C#

Tags: c#, tcp-ip, передача-данных, c++, клиент-сервер

Здравствуйте, есть две программы, одна программа сервер (Linux) написанная на c++ вторая программа клиент(Windows) написанная на C#.

**Суть**: От сервера к клиенту идёт передача файлов разных размеров.

**Проблема**: Клиент принимает файлы без потерь до 150мб +- 50мб (приблизительно), после 150мб идёт потеря данных файл получается не полный, например если передаю 506мб, получаю 450 +- 20мб а то и меньше например 200мб. Цикл клиента просто останавливается в ожидании приема байт которых сервер уже отправил, но они не дошли до клиента.

Приведу код клиента, прием файла.

Переменная **filesize** содержит размер файла, переменная **FileName** содержит название файла.

```
using (FileStream fsRecieve = File.Open(FileName, FileMode.OpenOrCreate))
            {
                Buffer = new byte[2048]; 
                do
                {
                    fsRecieve.Write(Buffer, 0, bytesRead);
                    filesize -= bytesRead;
                    if (filesize == 0) break;
                }
                while (((bytesRead = TcpStream.Read(Buffer, 0, Buffer.Length)) > 0));
            }
```

Код сервера отправка файла. 
**f** - это указатель на файл **FILE *f;**, нижние два условия цикла делают паузу на одну секунду через каждые 3мб.

```
long long flsize;
flsize = filesize / 3145728; 
while(!feof(f)) //пока не конец файла, передаем частями файл (сколько помещается в буфере)
{
    /*Берем кусок от файла 2048 байт*/
    symbols=fread(bufer,1,2048,f);
    size=ftell(f);//функция возвращает текущую позицию
    printf("read symbols: %d, part: %d, pos: %ld partes: %ld\n",symbols,i,size      );
    send(id,bufer,symbols,0);//передача содержимого буфера
    i++;
    filesize -= 2048;
    if(filesize > 3145728)
    {
       if((filesize / 3145728) < flsize)
       {
         flsize -= 1;
         sleep(1);
       }
     }
```

Сервер отправил данные но условие в цикле клиента не срабатывает.

```
filesize -= bytesRead;
if (filesize == 0) break;
```

Потому что, клиент не получил от сервера все байты согласно условию размера файла - количество принятых байт, если сервер отключить срабатывает условие цикла клиента.

```
 while (((bytesRead = TcpStream.Read(Buffer, 0, Buffer.Length)) > 0));
```

**Вопрос в следующем:** Почему происходит потеря данных при передачи свыше 150мб?

Comment: При отправке данных следует учитывать возвращаемое значение количества переданных данных. Для начала стоит обратить на это внимание.

Comment: Если вы имеете ввиду количество отправленных данных от сервера к клиенту, то на сервере стоит счетчик отправленных данных filesize при распечатки можно наблюдать как filesize стремится к нулю.
Если вы имеете ввиду подтверждение принятых байт от клиента к серверу в рамках стандартных запросов TCP, объясните по подробно логику действий.

Тут ещё вот такой момент: Если рассмотреть протокол Tcp подробно то мы увидим что пакеты идут друг за другом имея свой номер подтверждения длиной в 32 бит. Может быть такое что число выходит за приделы 32 бит? (К концу операции, пакетов то не 10 штук)

Comment: ну и пусть себе выходят. Начнут с начала. В протоколе tcp предусмотрено окно, в котором собираются пакеты. В пределах окна номера повторятся не будут.

Допустим, что каждый пакет передает по одному байту (вырожденный случай, но нам нужно быстро истратить все номера). В этом случае можно будет передать 2^32 байт, то есть, 4 гигабайта как минимум.

На самом деле у Вашего кода проблема в том, что Вы не проверяете код ответа send. В [доках](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms740149(v=vs.85).aspx) сказано, что send возвращает кол-во удачно отправленых байт.

Comment: Благодарю за ответ, ситуация проясняется сейчас попробую сделать следующие: Отправить пакет и проверить на успех отправки в случае не удачной отправки повторить пакет, если через n попыток повторно отправленный  пакет даст результат нулевой то -> Клиент отключился.
По поводу очереди пакетов: У меня сервер на множество клиентов, очередь пакетов идёт индивидуально для каждого клиента или для всех сразу?

Comment: поправка - пакет может не отправиться с припиской "нужно повторить ещё (код возврата в этом случае отрицательный). А также, может быть ситуация, когда Вы отправляете 5 кб, а send возвратит, 4000. Значит ещё 5*1024-4000 данных нужно отправить ещё раз. Или в комплекте с следующими данными. Если send возвратил 0 - значит клиент с той стороны закрыл соединение.

Comment: Логическая реализация данной проверки ставит в тупик мои знания, вы не могли бы расписать подробно последовательность действий для реализации такой проверки в коде?

Comment: Посмотрите на реализацию своего кода, который читает данные. Там используется такая же логика. И чуточку погуглите, ну самую малость - [sendall](http://beej.us/guide/bgnet/output/html/singlepage/bgnet.html#sendall)

Comment: К сожалению не уловил из текста вопроса *тонкий момент* с реализацией закрытия соединения на стороне сервера.

В любом случае, ознакомьтесь с linger options и shutdown.

Если после передачи файла соединение закрывается, то видимо наиболее безопасным будет такая схема (при условии, что размер файла известен клиенту):

- после отправки всех данных *сервер выполняет recv()* (на самом деле он ждет закрытия соединения). Получив 0 (или -1, но это ошибка), сервер вызывает `close()`.

- клиент читает все данные. После их получения он делает `close()`, тем самым инициируя разрыв соединения.

Comment: Сделал такую проверку.
`
  popitka = 0;
 do
  {

     bytesize =  send(id,bufer,symbols,0);
     popitka += 1;
     printf("read symbols: %d, part: %d, pos: %ld partes: %ld\n",symbols,i,size1);
     if(popitka > 5)
       {
          sleep(1);
          if(popitka > 20) sleep(10000);
        }
     }
    while(bytesize != symbols);
`
В консоли видно что очень часто идёт повтор пакетов, но они удачно отправляются не более чем через 20 попыток, программа не разу не стояла по условию sleep(10000), но файл выходит по прежнему битый. Сейчас попробую другой вариант решения из ссылки -> **KoVadim**

Comment: @updaite, это принципиально неверный код. Ваша концептуальная ошибка в том, что в TCP **нет пакетов**. TCP это **поток** байт.

Результатом вызова `send()` может быть или -1 (это ошибка, какая именно можно узнать из `errno`) или число *больше 0* (сколько байт из запрошенных `symbols` реально передано в ядро для отправки).

Вы же, если не все `symbols` байт отправлены, постоянно повторяете передачу целого буфера.

Т.е. писать надо что-то такое

      char *bufer = ...;
    
      if ((bytesize = send(...)) == -1) error(...);
      else {
         symbols -= bytesize; bufer += bytesize;
      }

Comment: Я думаю вопрос был бы актуален... ну например в рамках передачи файла частями по http протоколу. Или другим извесным способом.